# argparse: Dynamically use the value chosen for earlier argument for later argument

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to use an argument for a later argument?

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def get_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser(description="Data Generator")
    parser.add_argument('--name', required=True, type=str, help='Pick one: x, y, z')
    parser.add_argument('--save_path', type=str, default='C:/Users/User1/Desktop/', help='The save path')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

For instance, I would like to use the value the user includes in `--name` to be later and automatically tacked on the `--save_path` value. How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` is nothing but a [simple container object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) that holds its values as attributes. You can just modify it before returning it.

Given that `name` and `save_path` seem to be directory or file names, you could use `os.path.join` to add `name` to `save_path`.

```
import os.path

# ...

def get_args():
    # ...
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.save_path = os.path.join(args.save_path, args.name)
    return args
```